# how to load a csv file if multiple columns contain multiple commas in between using sparksql 1.6v

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, spark-csv

how to load a csv file if multiple columns contain multiple commas in between using sparksql 1.6v for example given csv file contains some records similar to below.

```
col1, col2, col3, col4, col5
abc, xyz, pqr, p,q, qq pr,tt
```

now `col1` should contain `abc`

```
col2 xyz, pqr
col3 p,q
col4 qq pr
col5 tt
```

In spark dataframe using spark 1.6v.

Comment: What logic determines that 2 is `xyz, pqr` and 1 is not `abc, xyz` ?

Comment: Actually I have records available in csv file so by looking I know this data should come under col1 or col2. But when I am trying to load csv file using com.databricks.spark.csv in sparksql to create dataframe it receive column data like col1 contains abc, col2 contains xyz, col3 pqr and so on. it end up with column data mismatch.

Comment: *so by looking I know this data should come under col1 or col2* - You need to articulate this in code & parse it manually, if there is additional parsing logic what you have is not really a CSV file.

Comment: csv file data is huge in size contains million of records so not feasible to parse manually and one more thing sequence of getting multiple commas is not fix so any of given columns can contain multiple columns as a result.

Comment: could any spark developer provide their insight on the same it will be really helpful.

Comment: Basically, if you do not tell us how you determine which commas should not be taken into account and which ones are actual separators, we cannot do anything for you.

Comment: You need to write custom parser for this. I agree with other users. I would suggest please check what is the source of this file and on what basis the segregation is happening for the column